# Change of columns when deriving the inverse of the coefficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it not allowed to interchange columns, when trying to find the inverse of the coefficient matrix by use of of elementary operations?
We do not need it since the square matrix is invertible. Even if we did use it, we would be just changing the order of the variables, but maintaining the same set of systems of linear equations...no?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: No problem even thought colum operation is being done.  Let A be matrix. row operation means that Left product EA, colum operation means that Right proud AE. If you want to find inverse, You choose only one way of iterative left product and right proudct.

Comment: @Planche can both iterations be used in the same process, i.e. row and column interchange?

Comment: Ah, Actually Yes .

Comment: Let $E_i$ be elementary matrixes so that $E_1 E_2 E_3 .. E_k A E_{k+1} ... E_{r} = I$. then $A^{-1}=(E_1 E_2 E_3 .. E_k)^{-1}(E_{k+1} ... E_{r})^{-1}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Really, I don't understand yet.

Comment: Let me explain what @Planche means through an example: interchanging the colums of $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is realized through a right multiplication by $E=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Right ? (pun intended). Then taking the inverse after having interchanged columns is not neutral, because in this case, instead of having $A^{-1}$, one has $(AE)^{-1}=E^{-1}A^{-1}$ whis is not at all the same thing as $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for clarification of the intent. @JeanMarie

Comment: @JeanMarie Now I'm the one who's not getting it... Can I use both operations in the same process?

Comment: I don't now very well what you mean by this question. My example was there to say that exchanging colums is like introducing a new matrix into the process : thus you think that inversing $AE$ is like inversing $A$ and I say no, you inverse $AE$ so you get $(AE)^{-1}=E^{-1}A^{-1}$ instead of $A^{-1}$, which means an exchange of lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do elementary operations on rows of the matrix $A$, you pre-multiply $A$ by a matrix of elementary operation. For operations on columns, you post-multiply by a another matrix of elementary operation. Thus if you do both until you obtain the unit matrix, you have matrices of elementary operations $E_1,\dots, E_r$ and $F_1\dots F_s$ such that
$$E_1\dotsm E_r A F_1\dotsm F_s=Y,$$
i.e. you've found two matrices $E=E_1,\dots, E_r$ and $F=F_1\dotsm F_s$ such that $\;EAF=I$, which implies $\;F^{-1}A^{-1}E^{-1}=I$, whence
$$A^{-1}=FE.$$
However, when you apply the same transformations to the unit matrix, you obtain the matrix $EIF=EF$, which is different from $FE$ in general.

This explains why to find the inverse, you have to do elementary operations on either rows of columns but not both.

Comment: You complete my understanding.

Comment: many thanks Bernard! ;)

Comment: Bernard, one question. How would you tie your answer with the intuition in my question, i.e, as a method for solving a system of systems of linear equations. Where did I go wrong? ;)

Comment: Let's say that, if you change the order of the variables, the identity matrix is no more the identity matrix. The proof of Gauß's pivot matrix for computing the inverse relies on the fact that the required elementary matrices are reflected on the operations on the unit matrix, but you forgot the order in the product is important so that, in a rather subtle way, you thought the order was correct at each step when it wasn't.

Comment: I think I get it. ;)